# Is the natural logarithm of $a$ irrational if $a \neq 0,1$ is algebraic?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

1. Starting with the result of the [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem): $$ a^b = c$$ where a and b are complex algebraic numbers with $a \neq 0,1$, and $b$ not rational and $c$ is transcendental.
2. Substitute the exponential number $e$ for c: $$ a^b = e$$
3. Raise both sides to the power of $(1/b)$ to obtain: $$a = e^{(1/b)}.$$
4. Take the natural log of both sides: $$\ln(a) = \ln(e^{(1/b)}) = (1/b).$$

Assuming that $(1/b)$ is not rational, since b is not rational, this suggests that the natural logarithm of any algebraic number (irrational, rational or complex) $ \neq 0,1, $ is a non-rational algebraic number.

Hopefully, the issue of countable versus uncountable that flawed my last attempt is not an issue here.

Are there any counter examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the Gelfond-Schneider theorem.  Just the transcendence of $e$ is enough.

To prove $r = \log a$ is irrational, suppose it is rational. Then $e^r = a$, so $e^r$ is algebraic. Since $a \not= 1$, $r \not= 0$.

Writing $r = m/n$ with integers $m$ and $n$, $(e^r)^n = e^{rn} = e^m$ is algebraic and $m \not= 0$.

Hermite showed is 1873 that $e$ is transcendental, so $e^m$ is transcendental when $m$ is a nonzero integer. Thus we have a contradiction, so $\log a$ is irrational.